# Joining of curve fitting models

Tags: python-2.7, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have this 7 quasi-lorentzian curves which are fitted to my data.
[image]

and I would like to join them, to make one connected curved line. Do You have any ideas how to do this? I've read about `ComposingModel` at `lmfit` documentation, but it's not clear how to do this.

Here is a sample of my code of two fitted curves.

```
for dataset in [Bxfft]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    freqs, psd = signal.welch(dataset, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=16192, scaling='spectrum')
    plt.semilogy(freqs[0:-7000], psd[0:-7000]/dataset.size**0, color='r', label='Bx')
    x = freqs[100:-7900]
    y = psd[100:-7900]

    # 8 Hz
    model = Model(lorentzian)
    params = model.make_params(amp=6, cen=5, sig=1, e=0)
    result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
    final_fit = result.best_fit
    print "8 Hz mode"
    print(result.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
    plt.plot(x, final_fit, 'k-', linewidth=2)

    # 14 Hz
    x2 = freqs[220:-7780]
    y2 = psd[220:-7780]

    model2 = Model(lorentzian)
    pars2 = model2.make_params(amp=6, cen=10, sig=3, e=0)
    pars2['amp'].value = 6
    result2 = model2.fit(y2, pars2, x=x2)
    final_fit2 = result2.best_fit
    print "14 Hz mode"
    print(result2.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
    plt.plot(x2, final_fit2, 'k-', linewidth=2)
```

UPDATE!!!

I've used some hints from user @MNewville, who posted an answer and using his code I got this:
[image]

So my code is similar to his, but extended with each peak. What I'm struggling now is replacing ready `LorentzModel` with my own.

The problem is when I do this, the code gives me an error like this.

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lmfit\printfuncs.py:153: RuntimeWarning:
>   invalid value encountered in double_scalars [[Model]]   spercent =
>   '({0:.2%})'.format(abs(par.stderr/par.value))

About my own model:

```
    def lorentzian(x, amp, cen, sig, e):
         return (amp*(1-e)) / ((pow((1.0 * x - cen), 2)) + (pow(sig, 2)))

    peak1 = Model(lorentzian, prefix='p1_')
    peak2 = Model(lorentzian, prefix='p2_')
    peak3 = Model(lorentzian, prefix='p3_')

    # make composite by adding (or multiplying, etc) components
    model = peak1 + peak2 + peak3

    # make parameters for the full model, setting initial values
    # using the prefixes
    params = model.make_params(p1_amp=6, p1_cen=8, p1_sig=1, p1_e=0,
                               p2_ampe=16, p2_cen=14, p2_sig=3, p2_e=0,
                               p3_amp=16, p3_cen=21, p3_sig=3, p3_e=0,)
```

rest of the code is similar like at @MNewville

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A composite model for 3 Lorentzians would look like this:

```
from lmfit import Model, LorentzianModel
peak1 = LorentzianModel(prefix='p1_')
peak2 = LorentzianModel(prefix='p2_')
peak3 = LorentzianModel(prefix='p3_')

# make composite by adding (or multiplying, etc) components
model = peak1 + peaks2 + peak3

# make parameters for the full model, setting initial values 
# using the prefixes
params = model.make_params(p1_amplitude=10, p1_center=8, p1_sigma=3,
                           p2_amplitude=10, p2_center=15, p2_sigma=3,
                           p3_amplitude=10, p3_center=20, p3_sigma=3)

# perhaps set bounds to prevent peaks from swapping or crazy values
params['p1_amplitude'].min = 0
params['p2_amplitude'].min = 0
params['p3_amplitude'].min = 0
params['p1_sigma'].min = 0
params['p2_sigma'].min = 0
params['p3_sigma'].min = 0
params['p1_center'].min = 2
params['p1_center'].max = 11
params['p2_center'].min = 10
params['p2_center'].max = 18
params['p3_center'].min = 17
params['p3_center'].max = 25

# then do a fit over the full data range
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
```

I think the key parts you were missing were: a) just add models together, and b) use prefix to avoid name collisions of parameters.

I hope that is enough to get you started...

Comment: `amp` and `e` are completely correlated in your definition of Lorentzian.   Please (and, always) report the full and exact traceback.   I don't see how it is possible for Python2.7 to give a RuntimeWarning there.

Comment: Well sorry to disappoint, but that's the whole error. Look at my question, there You can find PS of my desktop.

Comment: I don't understand how that could be the entire message or how it could be interlaced with the output text and colorized.  But then, I don't understand why you post a screenshot as the output text... why not just post the text?   It looks like this may be from some Python-ish IDE or environment  -- I don't know what that is, but whatever is colorizing the text is probably "interpreting" the error message.   Of course, a complete minimal example and complete output are always a good idea.   Then again, the actual problem is already identified that `amp` and `e` are completely correlated.

Comment: Well this is what I have done, I copied the whole text, but You assumed that I didn't post the whole error. You say that `amp` and `e` are correlated. What should I change then? Note that in my former code, I had the same values as here for `amp` and `e`, but everything worked well, and there were no errors at all.

Comment: Well I've found out what is wrong. The problem was in the bounds. When I thrown them away, everything worked just fine, showing me values I was expected. I marked Your answer as the one which solves my problem, because without Your post I wouldn't finish it. So thank You for cooperation :)